# How to schedule a task in service fabric using 'Ac­tor Remin­der' mechanism?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-actor

I want to generate invoices on daily, weekly and monthly basis and want to send invoices periodically.
Each customer have different invoice settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometime ago I wondered how to do that myself. Based on the excellent [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-actors-timers-reminders#actor-reminders) I came up with a sample app, see my [repo](https://github.com/Expecho/Service-Fabric-Actors-Playground).

Your actor should implement the `IRemindable` interface.
To create a reminder use this in an actor method:

```
await RegisterReminderAsync(
            "MyReminder", // name of the reminder
            Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message), // byte array with payload (message is a string in my case)
            dueTime, // When is the reminder first activated
            snoozeTime); // Interval between activations
```

In your case set the snoozeTime to a day or to a week to have the reminder activate every period.

When the due time is there the method `ReceiveReminderAsync` is called:

```
public Task ReceiveReminderAsync(string reminderName, byte[] state, TimeSpan dueTime, TimeSpan period)
{
    ActorEventSource.Current.Message($"Actor recieved reminder {reminderName}.");

    ...
}
```

You can tell by the value of `ReceiveReminderAsync` which reminder it is about and you can use the content of `state` to act on the payload.

To dismiss a reminder use the `UnregisterReminderAsync` method:

```
await UnregisterReminderAsync(GetReminder("MyReminder"));
```

Comment: Great, let us know if it helped by [marking your question answered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) so other know wether they have to take a look as well or not :-)

Comment: whats the purpose of due time?

Comment: @SumeshEs due time is when the reminder should be activated for the first time. If you set it to `TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(0)` it will be active immediately after calling `RegisterReminderAsync`. If you set it to,say `TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)` it will be actived 5 minutes after the `RegisterReminderAsync` method is called.

Comment: When I schedule the tasks and set the due for 30 minutes or something like it will invoke thread.sleep method in Program.cs class. Why is it happening?

Answer (score 0):

```
internal class InvoiceGenerationActor : Actor, IInvoiceGenerationActor, IRemindable
{
    protected override async Task OnActivateAsync()
    {
        ////ActorEventSource.Current.ActorMessage(this, "Actor activated.");

        //// The StateManager is this actor's private state store.
        //// Data stored in the StateManager will be replicated for high-availability for actors that use volatile or persisted state storage.
        //// Any serializable object can be saved in the StateManager.
        //// For more information, see https://aka.ms/servicefabricactorsstateserialization

        //// return this.StateManager.TryAddStateAsync("count", 0);

        ////var schedulerDtos = GetSchedulerList();

        await base.OnActivateAsync();

        ActorEventSource.Current.ActorMessage(this, "Actor activated.");

        IActorReminder generationReminderRegistration = await this.RegisterReminderAsync(GenerationRemainder, BitConverter.GetBytes(100), TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(0), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));

        ////IActorReminder mailReminderRegistration = await this.RegisterReminderAsync(generationRemainder, BitConverter.GetBytes(100), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), TimeSpan.FromHours(1));

        return;
    }

    public async Task ReceiveReminderAsync(string reminderName, byte[] context, TimeSpan dueTime, TimeSpan period)
    {
        if (reminderName.Equals(GenerationRemainder))
        {
            await GetAllInvoiceSettingAndRegisterNewRemiders();
        }
        else
        {
            int solutionPartnerId = BitConverter.ToInt32(context, 0);
            var data = await Get("SolutionOwnerInvoiceGeneration/AutomaticInvoiceGeneration/" + solutionPartnerId, "PartnerService");
            await UnregisterReminderAsync(GetReminder(reminderName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a small description of what this does.

Comment: A question: I have a a service I want to do some work once per day. i see an Actor Reminder seems to be the suitable way to do it.  But where shall the Actor be created? the service fabric is a stateless service, is that service supposed to create the Actor in its constructor?

Answer (score -1):

For scheduled tasks, you can use an external mechanism like [hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/).

It does scheduled tasks apart from the web app and you can track tasks from its task dashboard.

You can register a job like:

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => SoccerDataFetcher_UpdatePlayersOfTeams(), Cron.Daily);
```

Comment: Yes hangfire is a good mechanism for scheduling task, but I would like to use the Reliable Actor model, the scheduling mechanism used in service fabric.

Comment: @SumeshEs then you should probably remove the asp.net tag. Not relevant to your question anyway.

Comment: @PeterBons Ok will do that